# Postgresql split_part get last index position

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I receive the name of the java exception class for example:

Say I have the following text captured in a db column:

```
`split_part('com.example.test.InvalidTradeTypeException', '.', 1 ) as exception_class`
```

I want the result of the `split_part()` to return `InvalidTradeTypeException` but I don't want to hard code the index position as the package structure can have many levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the top of my head I would do

```
reverse(split_part(reverse('com.example.test.InvalidTradeTypeException'),'.',1))
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '^.*[.]([^.]+)$', '\1')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5ee4648486a296a17e2fc2af64609c1) is a db<>fiddle.